# DatasSourceBuilder vs DriverManagerDataSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, connection-pooling, jdbctemplate

Creating DataSource using DatasSourceBuilder

```
@Bean
    DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        DatasSourceBuilder dataSource = DatasSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSource.url("");
        ...
        ..
        
        return dataSource.build();
        
    }
```

Creating DataSource using DriverManagerDataSource

```
@Bean
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("");
        ...
        ..
        
        return dataSource;
        
    }
```

I am creating jdbc with both of the above method

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate()
{
return new jdbcTemplate(dataSource());
}
```

I am uisng jdbcTemplate like below

```
void m1()
{
simpleJdbc = new simpleJdbc(jdbcTemplate);
simpleJdbc.execute(procedure)
}
```

So my question is if i call m1() 50 times repeatedly then how many connections will be created in both cases i.e DriverManagerDataSource and DatasSourceBuilder

Comment: `DriverManagerDataSource` -> 50, `DataSourceBuilder` -> depends on your max poolsize setting. You shouldn't be using the `DriverManagerDataSource` for in production, use it for tests and demos. It isn't a connection pool and will open a connection when needed (and closes it afterwards when properly setup). However opening a connection is slow and you want to pool connections using a proper connection pool.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum can you put your comment as answer. I will use DataSourceBuilder .Thanks

Comment: Why are ou even using the `DataSourceBuilder`? Spring Boot will automatically configure a datasource for you as well as a `JdbcTemplate`. Feels like you are working around the framework, unless you have multiple datasources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer is

- `DriverManagerDataSource` -> as many connections as you call the method
- `DataSourceBuilder` -> as many connections as specified by the max poolsize property.

However the real answer would be it depends. If you call `m1` in a single transaction and call it 50 times then it will open in either way just a single connection. The opened connection is bound to the transaction and reused.

That being said, you shouldn't be using `DriverManagerDataSource` for a production ready application. It isn't a connection pool and will open connections when needed, opening a connection is slow and it will create an unbounded number of connections (depending on the need) so if you have 100 requests needing a connection it will open 100 connections (probably flooding your DB).

Use `DriverManagerDataSource` only for tests and demos but not for production applications.

Comment: my last doubt is why 50 connections for DriverManagerDataSource ?Since i am using jdbctemplate..wont the jdbctemplate close the connection once the connection is used up.

Comment: Yes and it will use another one, and another one. So in the end it will have opened 50 connections (and closed them). Whilst the pool reuses already openend connections.